# cpanel cron job url

Tags: cron, cpanel

I need to create a cron job that runs a webpage (and retrieve some data) (not a file on the server). I tryed wget and it works if I set the cron job manually in unix, but not if I create the cron job in cpanel. Something like wget -O http://someurl.somehting.

Comment: Not a programming question, doesn't belong on SO, try http://www.superuser.com http://unix.stackexchange.com http://www.serverfault.com. Also completely unrelated to PHP, so don't tag it with PHP!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

cron jobs do not run under your user and environment. The path to `wget` may not be in the cron user's `PATH`. Specify the full path (e.g. `/usr/bin/wget`).